# How do I transpose a table in Pentaho Kettle from rows to columns without the header column

Tags: pentaho, transpose, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I'm new to Pentaho and I need to transpose a table from rows to columns, but the first column doesn't contain the headers.

It looks something like this:

```
Jan/15  Feb/15  Mar/15  Apr/15
1.1     3.4     1.7     2.0
2.5     4.5     2.4     3.3
```

And I need to convert to a table like the on below:

```
Month   Value A  Value B
Jan/15  1.1      2.5
Feb/15  3.4      4.5
Mar/15  1.7      2.4
Apr/15  2.0      3.3
```

Someone knows how can I achieve this? Is there some step that could help or only through scripts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to add the value name (`A` and `B`) to the row. And then first do a `Row Normaliser`, to make rows. Then you have to `Row denormaliser`, to get the two different values on the same row.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Convert string date, to date for correct sort:
[image: Screenshot of select values]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I did it here and solved it! =]

Comment: What about the other way around?I have a data set where as columns I do have Months, fieldA, fieldB, FieldB,FieldC...Field_N and I want the transpose to be Months as column and as rows all those fields, in the same excel sheet. I tried with same component, I got the transpose, but problem is to get differents months value as header for the columns. Either I missing something on how to use the denormaliser and normaliser or this specific task is not possible just with kettle and I should think of other solutions